# RegEx for capturing groups between repeated words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

The key words are "*OR" or "*AND".

Suppose I have the string below:

> This is a t3xt with special characters like !#. *AND and this is
>   another text with special characters *AND this repeats *OR do not
>   repeat *OR have more strings *AND finish with this string.

I want the following

```
group1 "This is a t3xt with special characters like !#."  
group2 "*AND"  
group3 "and this is another text with special characters"  
group4 "*AND"  
group5 "this repeats"  
group6 "*OR"  
group7 "do not repeat"  
group8 "*OR"  
group9 "have more strings"  
group10 "*AND"  
group11 "finish with this string."
```

I have tried like this:

```
(.+?)(\*AND\*OR)
```

but it only gets the first string then I need to keep repeating the code to collect the others, but the problem is that there are strings that have only one *AND, or only one *OR or dozens of it, that is pretty random. And the regex below also does not work:

```
((.+?)(\*AND\*OR))+
```

For example:

> This is a t3xt with special characters like !#. *AND and this is
>   another text with special characters

Comment: Please specify which language / regex engine. Also, using format/markup for your examples and expected matches may help us better understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have inserted expected matches. I am using php7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a [`preg_split`](https://php.net/preg_split) function for this sort of thing. `preg_split` allows you to split a string by a delimiter you can define as a regex pattern. In addition, it has an argument that allows you to include the matched delimiter in the matched/split results.

So, instead of writing a regex to match the full text, the regex is for the delimiter itself.

**Example:**

```
$string = "This is a t3xt with special characters like !#. *AND and this is another text with special characters *AND this repeats *OR do not repeat *OR have more strings *AND finish with this string.";
$string = preg_split('~(\*(?:AND|OR))~',$string,0,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($string);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is a t3xt with special characters like !#. 
    [1] => *AND
    [2] =>  and this is another text with special characters 
    [3] => *AND
    [4] =>  this repeats 
    [5] => *OR
    [6] =>  do not repeat 
    [7] => *OR
    [8] =>  have more strings 
    [9] => *AND
    [10] =>  finish with this string.
)
```

But if you really want to stick with using `preg_match`, you will instead need to use [`preg_match_all`](https://php.net/preg_match_all), which is similar to `preg_match` (what you tagged in your question), except that it does global/repeated matches.

**Example:**

```
$string = "This is a t3xt with special characters like !#. *AND and this is another text with special characters *AND this repeats *OR do not repeat *OR have more strings *AND finish with this string.";
preg_match_all('~(?:(?:(?!\*(?:AND|OR)).)+)|(?:\*(?:AND|OR))~',$string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is a t3xt with special characters like !#. 
            [1] => *AND
            [2] =>  and this is another text with special characters 
            [3] => *AND
            [4] =>  this repeats 
            [5] => *OR
            [6] =>  do not repeat 
            [7] => *OR
            [8] =>  have more strings 
            [9] => *AND
            [10] =>  finish with this string.
        )

)
```

First, note that unlike `preg_split`, `preg_match_all` (and `preg_match`) return a multi-dim array, not a single-dim. Secondly, technically, the pattern I used could be simplified a bit, but it would come at a cost of having to reference multiple arrays in the multi-dim array returned (one array for the matched text, and another array for the matched delimiters), that you would then have to loop through and alternate reference; IOW there would be additional cleanup to get a final single array with both match sets, as above.

I only show this method because you technically asked for it in your question, but I recommend using `preg_split`, as it takes away a lot of this overhead, and why it was created in the first place (to better solve scenarios like this).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works fine. I just did not understand the tilde meaning on the pattern.

Comment: @AndersonOliveira It is the pattern delimiter. PHP preg_xxx functions can use many different symbols as the pattern delimiter. One of the most commonly used is `/` forward slash. I personally use tilde because then I don't have to escape `/` when doing URL or directory based patterns, and it also just stands out more to me.

Comment: `preg_xxx` functions first argument expect a delimiter to be used to signify the start and end of your pattern, because flags are also put into the string. For example, changing the first argument to `'~(\*(?:AND|OR))~i'` (with an `i` on the end there) will make the match case-insensitive.

Comment: Got it @CrayonViolent, Thanks for the explanation!